# Sitecore Collection databases not created in Prod xConnect Set up using SIF

Tags: xdb, xconnect, sitecore-install-framework

While we are doing xConnect Prod set up, identified that following collection DBs are not created post SIF script execution.

Missed collection DBs:

1.Xdb.Collection.Shard0

2.Xdb.Collection.Shard1

3.Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager

So did the below steps to fix the issue.

1.Removed the Processing, reporting databases which got created as part of xConnect setup

2.Removed services which are created as part of xConnect set up

3.Uninstall the set up and execute the script once again.

But sill no luck.
We got below exception while executing through SIF:

`"/dbedition was not specified"`

Error details:
While running using SIF:
[image]

While ran the SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe using create command:
[image]

We are doing set up for Sitecore 9.2 and On Premises set up. We are using SA account while executing scripts. Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the two errors that you experienced have the exact same error message, the reason why each error occurs is different.

The error during the SIF installation occurs if you have double quote (`"`) characters in your connection string value. From your SIF installation screenshot, it looks like you have some double quote characters wrapping the `Data Source` value in the connection string.

The error in the manual execution of the SQL Sharding Deployment Tool command is instead occurring because the order of the input parameters is not correct, as described on the official documentation [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/the-sql-sharding-deployment-tool.html#parameters):

> Different operations accept a specific set of parameters **in a specific order**.

The `/dbedition` input parameter is expected by the tool as third parameter right after the `/connectionstring` parameter, but in your manual execution is in a different order. Also, your command is missing the `/shardMapNames` input parameter too.

This is an example of command for the `create` operation:

```
Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe /operation "create" /connectionstring "Data Source=.;user id=sa;password=12345;" /dbedition "Basic" /shardMapManagerDatabaseName "TestDatabase" /shardMapNames "ContactIdShardMap,DeviceProfileIdShardMap,ContactIdentifiersIndexShardMap" /shardnumber 2 /shardnameprefix "Shard_" /shardnamesuffix "_" /dacpac "Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.Sql.dacpac"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I dont think double quote (") creates issue here as we were able to create other DBs with same conn.strings. Moreover, \dbedition is only applicable for Azure Sql as in the document. But we are setting up on premises environment. For on premises also, dbedition expected?

Comment: Other databases are created differently in the SIF installation process. Only collection shard databases are created using the SQL Sharding Deployment Tool. You can reproduce the issue executing the same command with double quotes in connection string parameter in PowerShell (where SIF runs). For the /dbedition parameter, this is a mandatory parameter (as described in documentation) and it needs to be included even if it is applicable for Azure SQL only.